# AngularJS: ui-select accept string instead of array

Tags: angularjs

Using angularjs here.

I am using ui-select for allowing the user to select multiple values as:

```
<div class="form-group" ng-repeat="(name, data) in usersets" ng-class="{ 'has-error': form[inputName + $index].$invalid && submitted }">
   <ui-select name="{{inputName + $index}}" class="btn m-grid-col-md-3" ng-model="data.value" theme="bootstrap">
        <ui-select-match placeholder="data">{{data.value}}</ui-select-match>
        <ui-select-choices repeat="data in data.userValue | filter: $select.search track by $index">
            <div ng-bind-html="data"></div>
        </ui-select-choices>
    </ui-select>
</div>
```

I have used the below line to bind the UI select to an array so that it can show all set of options when user starts to type in it.

```
<ui-select-choices repeat="data in data.userValue | filter: $select.search track by $index">
```

My issue is because some changes data.userValue above is not returning an array but just a single string value.

If I try to use the same code above I get error on console as:

```
[ui.select:items] Expected an array but got 'myString'
```

'myString' is the string returned from data.userValue

Could anyone point me as to what changes do I need to make above to make it accept a single string instead of an array.

Thanks

Comment: What is the value of `data.userValue`? If it's a comma-delimited list (or something similar) you could easily convert it to an array in your controller and use the array instead.

Comment: It is no an array. It just a string ex "myString". This all is a part of directive. Is it possible to convert this to array in html only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The `ng-repeat` collection must be an array or an object.](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_ng-repeat.asp)

> As per your comment : It is no an array. It just a string ex "myString". This all is a part of directive. Is it possible to convert this to array in html only?

Try this

`repeat="data in [data.userValue]`

Comment: Ramesh, can you also look at my post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57482810/angularjs-ui-select-selected-text-and-value